# How To Call on Dictionary Inside Class

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I have been working with a lot of dictionaries within my newest app in preparation for working with JSON, but I cannot call on a dictionary that is inside a class but I can call on a dictionary outside of a class. For example, whenever i try to call on the dictionary, either inside or outside the class I get an error:

```
class NUMBERS {

    var Numbers: [String:Int] = [

        "One" : 1,
        "Two" : 2,
        "Three" : 3

    ]

    print("\(Numbers.count)") // error

}

print("\(Numbers.count)") // error
```

But when I call on a dictionary outside of a class like below, there is no error. Any help or advice would be great. So, if it is possible, how do you call on a dictionary inside of a class. Thank you!

```
import UIKit
var numbers: [String:Int] = [

    "One" : 1,
    "Two" : 2,
    "Three" : 3

]

NSLog("\(numbers["One"])") // no error
```

Comment: You can't just have code (minus properties) floating in the class body, you need to put it inside a method. Also following standard naming conventions, your class should be called `Numbers`, and you property should be called `numbers`.

Comment: I think you should read some articles or books about OOP (Object Oriented Programming) to understand what is a method, what is an object, what is a scope and how the environment of class interacts within properties and objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just randomly print something. You have to do it inside a function or method etc.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("\(Numbers.count)")
}
```